# Drupal 7 - making a block grouping event per month in tabs

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, calendar

I have been looking all over the internet but can't find a decent tutorial on how to get this done. What I want to achieve is a block on the front page which shows all event happening within a certain month, with tabs on top showing the various months, kind of like the calendar on http://www.brusselsphilharmonic.be/home/. From what I have found, Quicktabs is the way to go. However, I am not sure exactly how to create a single view based on the date field in the event content type, and make it dynamically show per month . I want to avoid having to make a different view per month, so I am looking into a way to use arguments to have one view dynamically generate a monthly overview of events per tab. Being quite new to Drupal, I am a bit at odds with this complexity, has someone already created an event overview like the one I described? If so, could you tell me if I am on the right track to solving this? I would like to only have the client fill out the different events planned, with all the data automatically shown in the right places... Thanks in advance for some tips and (hopefully) a newbie tutorial on how to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a bit of elbow grease I managed to get this to work on my own. Here's how:

1. Create a content type that has a date field, let's call it calendar item
2. Create a block view (I called mine Calendar). I just made an unordered list simply showing the content of every calendar item, but a teaser or any other display works as well. I filtered on published: yes and type: calendar item, sorted ascended.
3. In the view, make sure you add a contextual filter. Also make sure you pick the content:date field that shows up in the calendar item content type. If you are only using this view to show a tabbed calendar on the front page, you can choose to show all results when no filter value occurs in the URL. When filter values do occur, select accuracy: month. Date range is something you can choose for yourself, I took 0,+5 to be sure. Then hit apply.
4. Go to structure > quicktabs and add a new quicktabs instance. I called mine calendar. Renderer should be quicktabs, pick a style that best fits your needs. For this rather limited use of Quicktabs, I would suggest loading all tabs on page load, and hide the empty tabs.
5. In the quicktabs instance, make a separate tab for every month. For every month, select type:view, choose Calendar, display:block. Depending on the month, use the argument yyyymm (e.g. for September 2014: 201409). Repeat for every month and hit save. After enabling the Quicktabs block under structure > blocks, enjoy your calendar!

P.S. make sure you use the latest dev version of quicktabs for this, the recommended version (3.6) gave some tab loading errors in which tabs would disappear once you've selected them.